# Strange behaviour -> .GetEnumerator() | .Reset() -> Looking for a way around

Tags: xml, powershell, enumerator

I am working with a simple XML file in PowerShell and since I use the `GetEnumerator()` method I see some strange things when working with my script. When I save something in an object with the `GetEnumerator()` method, I can use the object only once. After that I have to make a reset to use it again.

I want to get rid of this behaviour. Below is a sample script, which basically shows how I use it in my script. In my real script in the function I use the variable `$ControlObject` very often and I have to reset it each time.

How can I prevent this in an easy way?

```bsh
$XMLTargetPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "XMLConfig.xml"

# Save XML in File for easy and fast reproduction
$XMLContentForFile = [xml]@"
<OuterNode>
  <BaseSettings>
    <Setting1>Blabla</Setting1>
  </BaseSettings>
  <DynamicSettings>
    <item>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Name>January</Name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Number>2</Number>
        <Name>February</Name>
    </item>
  </DynamicSettings>
</OuterNode>
"@
$XMLContentForFile.Save($XMLTargetPath)

function MyFunction {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        $ControlObject
    )

    $ControlObject     # Output the Object
    $ControlObject     # PROBLEM - I get no output ...

    # I need to make a reset to output the object again ...
    $ControlObject.Reset()
    $ControlObject
}

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $XMLTargetPath

# Pass the XML-Node "Dynamic-Settings" into Function
MyFunction -ControlObject $xml.OuterNode.DynamicSettings.GetEnumerator()
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Outputs both items twice for me

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The OP expects the output to appear three times: twice before the reset, once afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the enumerator and PowerShell default output work. PowerShell [automagically appends `| Out-Default`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/29/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/) for output handling:

> It calls the engine to get the prompt but then it displays it and collects user input.  It then takes that input, concatenates `| Out-Default` and submits it to the engine for execution.  … YES, under the covers every command entered in through the console host is piped to `Out-Default`.

The pipeline, however, automatically unrolls enumerators (otherwise it wouldn't be able to display the elements of an enumeration or enumerable collection). Because of that, just echoing a variable is essentially the same as looping over the [enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx):

```
while ($ControlObject.MoveNext()) {
    $ControlObject.Current
}
```

After the output operation the enumerator is positioned at the end of the enumeration, so you need to move it to the beginning first before you can enumerate the elements again. That's what `Reset()` does.

Why does the pipeline not automatically reset the enumeration? I don't know, but probably to not produce an infinite loop.

*Bottom line:* You can't have the cake and eat it too. The enumeration needs to be unrolled so the elements can be displayed, and since the enumeration isn't reset automagically you need to do that yourself before you can enumerate the elements again.

If you just want the nested elements of the selected node you should probably use the [`ChildNodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx) property instead of an enumerator.

```
MyFunction -ControlObject $xml.OuterNode.DynamicSettings.ChildNodes
```

Comment: Can't I save the contents of the enumeration in an object to get the beaviour of a "normal" object and how in an easy way?

Comment: @Walhalla How about you simply don't use an enumerator when you don't want an enumerator? `$xml.OuterNode.DynamicSettings.ChildNodes` is what you actually want.

Comment: I need to test it further, but I think "$xml.OuterNode.DynamicSettings.ChildNodes" is the answer ;-)

Comment: If you post this as answer, perhaps with a comparison/description of ".ChildNotes" vs ".GetEnumerator", i will mark it as answer! Thank you so much